# Enter and exit animations not working in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

**What I'm trying to do:**

Screen one goes to left. Screen two comes from the right to center. When this happens, there's 50% transparent black overlay on screen one which appears 'slowly' and disappears 'slowly' when the reverse happens. I'm trying to do it slowly using fadeIn() and fadeOut().

**What is happening:**

The dark overlay appears and disappears instantly.

Here's the code:

```
if(navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route == "ScreenTwo"){
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = true,
            enter = fadeIn(
                animationSpec = tween(500)
            ),
            exit = fadeOut(
                animationSpec = tween(500)
            )
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
            )
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the complete code:

```
package com.example.slidehorizontalsample

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentTransitionScope
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.EnterTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.ExitTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.animation.fadeIn
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(){

    val isButtonClicked = remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "ScreenOne",
        enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
        exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None }
    ){
        composable(
            "ScreenOne",
            enterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(
                    animationSpec = tween(500),
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    animationSpec = tween(1000),
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start
                )
            }
        ){
            ScreenOne(navController)
        }
        composable(
            "ScreenTwo",
            enterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(
                    animationSpec = tween(500),
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    animationSpec = tween(500),
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End
                )
            }
        ){
            ScreenTwo(navController)
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun ScreenOne(navController: NavController){

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ){
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate("ScreenTwo")
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Go To Screen Two")
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route == "ScreenTwo",
        enter = fadeIn(
            animationSpec = tween(500)
        ),
        exit = fadeOut(
            animationSpec = tween(500)
        )
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenTwo(navController: NavController){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){
        Button(
            onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Go To Screen One")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the dark overlay appear and disappears instantly because AnimatedVisibility is in a your if condition.

You should try something like this :

```
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route == "ScreenTwo",
        enter = fadeIn(
            animationSpec = tween(500)
        ),
        exit = fadeOut(
            animationSpec = tween(500)
        )
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But there's one issue. The exit animation is still not working. As in, when going from screen 2 to 1, it should slowly make the overlay disappear but there is no overlay when going from screen 2 to 1.

Comment: When going from screen 2 to 1 the screen 2 disappear instantly without any animation ?

Comment: The dark overlay on screen 1 disappears instantly when going from screen 2 to screen 1.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add more code about screen 1 visibility ?

Comment: I've added the complete code above.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. You want that the dark overlay on screen 1 fade out when going from screen 2 to 1 ? 
You're missing the exit animation in AnimatedVisibility :
 `exit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(500))`
 in complete code

Comment: sorry. i had removed that 'exit' code becuz it wasn't working. I have updated the code again. I had that code earlier.

What I'm looking for is, screen transition. Screen 1 is at the bottom of screen 2. When going from screen 2 to screen 1, there should be a dark overlay on screen 1 which 'fades out' slowly.

Comment: I don't know why, but I have the impression that with Jetpack composites, the output animation is always faster than the enter animation. Try setting the fade out animation to 2000ms

Comment: Didn't work. Tried 3000 as well.